# $x^2+y^2$, quasiconcavity and upper level set

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, economics

I am having some trouble wrapping my head around quasiconcavity. I have a couple of definitions:

1. A function $f$ defined on a convex set $S$ is quasiconcave if every upper level set of $f$ is convex. That is, $P_a = {x ∈ S: f(x) ≥ a}$ is convex for every value of $a$.
2. A function $f:S\to \mathbb{R} $ defined on a convex subset $S$ of a real vector space is quasiconcave if $f(\lambda x + (1 - \lambda)y)\geq\min\big\{f(x),f(y)\big\}$.

Now given the function $f(,)=^2+^2 $, which is convex:

[image]

To me it looks as if the upper contour/upper level set is convex:

[image]

which according to definition (1) would imply the function is also quasiconcave.

However, looking at definition (2):

Choose two points $f_u(2,0)=4$, and $f_v(0,2)=4$, we get

$\min\{f_u, f_v\}=4$.

So $f(\lambda f_u + (1-\lambda)f_v)  $, which for $\lambda=0.5$ gives

$f(0.5(2,0) + 0.5(0,2))=f(1,1)=2$.

Hence, $f(\lambda f_u + (1-\lambda)f_v)\ngeq \min\big\{f_u,f_v\big\}$, thus failing definition (2) for quasiconcavity.

It passes definition (1) but not definition (2). What am I doing wrong here? (I suspect it has to do with my understanding of the upper level set)

Comment: The upper levels of the function $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ are the outsides of the circles, not the insides. So they are not convex.

Comment: Thank you !  that makes sense. A follow-up would be, is there an easy way to verify that the upper level sets of the function are (or are not) convex? In this case, I thought they were (and the contour plot looked to me to be convex) but you’re right, they are the outsides of the circles, which is clear by looking at the plot of the function but still not clear to me from looking at the level sets. So how to determine it from the level sets when the function is similar to this and the contours “look” convex (without looking at the function itself, or when the function is in higher dimensions)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the function $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ is convex, hence it is quasiconvex. Converse may not be true.

And you showed it:
$$f(\lambda a+(1-\lambda)b)\le \max(f(a),f(b)) \iff \\
f(\frac12(2,0)+\frac12(0,2))\le \max(f(2,0),f(0,2)) \iff \\
f(1,1)\le \max(4,4)\\
2\le 4.$$
The function $f(x,y)=-x^2-y^2$ is concave, hence it is quasiconcave. And both definitions of quasiconcavity will be valid for it.

Can you confirm it?

Comment: I can confirm that. However, as I mentioned to Luca Carai above, I’m not sure how to determine that from the level sets only as the level sets for the $x^2+y^2$ tripped me up.

Comment: The graph of $z=x^2+y^2$ is the parabaloid that opens up. The level set above certain level is the concave set with open center. Similarly, the graph of $z=-x^2-y^2$ is the parabaloid that opens down. The level set above certain level is the convex set of a circle. Hence, the results.